# Condition for the difference to belong to the open set.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and let $x\in U$ be a point such that $\text{dist}(x,\partial U)>\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon>0$. Now, let $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I have to find a condition for which $x-y\in U$.

I thought about this:

> $$x-y\in U \iff \text{dist}(x-y,\partial U)>0$$

> **Question**  it's correct? If it is not correct what should I show?
>
> That is, what I want to solve is the following problem: what does mean $x-y\in U$ in terms of distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct. For example, $y=Nx$ with large enough $N$ would be a counter-example. However, you can write  $$x-y\in U \iff \text{dist}(x-y,\mathbb R^{n}\setminus U)>0$$